# How to show data point labels in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, charts, label, datapoint

I cannot see any properties  to show data point labels in Silverlight (should be visible always) and Google doesn't give any joy...

Any clue how to do it?

Here is my XAML

```
  <toolkit:Chart Height="400" Width="600" Title="Cumulative Age Dispersions" >


                <toolkit:Chart.Axes>
                    <toolkit:CategoryAxis Title="Content Items"  Orientation="X" />
                    <toolkit:CategoryAxis Title="Seconds" Orientation="Y" Location="Right" />
                </toolkit:Chart.Axes>

                <toolkit:ColumnSeries  Title="Male" ItemsSource="{Binding MaleSerie}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding ItemName}"
                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Count}"   ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Count}"
                    AnimationSequence="Simultaneous" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="304" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266"/>

                <toolkit:ColumnSeries  Title="Female" ItemsSource="{Binding FemaleSerie}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding ItemName}"
                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Count}"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Count}"
                    AnimationSequence="Simultaneous" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="304" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266">


                </toolkit:ColumnSeries>

            </toolkit:Chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok done...

```
        <toolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <toolkit:CategoryAxis Title="Content Items"  Orientation="X" />
            <toolkit:CategoryAxis Title="Seconds" Orientation="Y" Location="Right" />
        </toolkit:Chart.Axes>

        <toolkit:ColumnSeries  Title="Male" ItemsSource="{Binding MaleSerie}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding ItemName}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Count}"   ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Count}"
            AnimationSequence="Simultaneous" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="304" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266"/>

        <toolkit:ColumnSeries  Title="Female" ItemsSource="{Binding FemaleSerie}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding ItemName}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Count}"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Count}"
            AnimationSequence="Simultaneous" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="304" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266">

            <toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle
                            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Stroke="Black"/>
                                    <Grid
                            Background="#aaffffff"
                            Margin="0 -40 -10 0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock
                                Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"
                                FontWeight="Bold" Width="40"
                                Margin="2"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </toolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>

        </toolkit:ColumnSeries>

    </toolkit:Chart>
```